# Probability that all intervals intersect

Tags: probability

Suppose $n\in \mathbb{N^*}$, $n\ge2$. $a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ are independent random variables uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, i.e. $a_k, b_k\sim U(0,1)$.

Let $I_k$ be the interval $[min(a_k,b_k),max(a_k,b_k)]$, $\forall k\in[n]$. Find out the probability that $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}I_k\not=\emptyset$$

I tried to list all the possibities and by induction. But neither of them seem to work. Could anyone give me some help?

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_{2n}$ denote the endpoints of the $n$ intervals. 
The numbers $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$, $b_1$, $\ldots$, $b_n$ are a 
random permutation of $x_1$, ..., $x_{2n}$, with each permutation being equally likely.

Then the intersection of all $n$ intervals is nonempty, if and only if for each $i$ one of $a_i$ and $b_i$ lies in $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and the other lies in $\{x_{n+1},\ldots,x_{2n}\}$. Out of all $(2n)!$ possible permutations of $x_1$, ..., $x_{2n}$, there are $2^n n!$ with this property.

Therefore, the required probability is
$$
\frac{2^n n!}{ (2n)!} = \frac{1}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdots \frac{1}{2n-1}.
$$

Comment: Hi, the bulk of the reasoning looks correct to me, just the last computation seems to be missing a factor of $n!$. We can order each of $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ and $\{x_{n+1},...,x_{2n}\}$ in $n!$ ways, so the answer should be $\frac{2^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}$.